# preg_match() no extrae todas las coincidencias

Tags: php, regex

Tengo este pequeño código PHP:

```
<?php
$r = file("id.txt");
$content = implode(" ",$r);

if (preg_match('#"name":[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $content, $datos)) {
    $mp = $datos[1];
} else {
    $mp = 'error';
}
echo $mp;

?>
```

Que se encarga de abrir y buscar usando preg_match() el contenido de

```
"name":"contenido"
```

con la ayuda de expresiones regulares dentro del archivo "id.txt".

Contenido del "id.txt":

```
"name":"jose";
"name":"juan";
"name":"carlos";
"name":"luis";
```

Son más de 50 líneas lo que contiene

> ```
> "name":""
> ```

con diferentes nombres .

Todo sale bien. El detalle es que solo me da el primer nombre y lo que pretendo es sacar todos los nombres y almacenarlos en una variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) devuelve sólo la primera coincidencia.

Para obtener todas, deberías usar [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags [, int $offset ]]] )
```

---

Código:

```
<?php
//comentado para que no haga falta el archivo
//$content = file_get_contents('id.txt'); 

//En cambio lo simulamos asignando el texto
$content = '"name":"jose";
"name":"juan";
"name":"carlos";
"name":"luis";';

if (preg_match_all('#"name":[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $content, $resultado)) {
    $mp = $resultado[1];   //que sólo tome lo capturado por el primer grupo
} else {
    $mp = ['sin coincidencias'];
}

//var_export($mp);  //mostramos el resultado, también se podría usar un foreach

//Mostramos el contenido del array
foreach ($mp as $nombre) {
    echo $nombre . "<br>\n";
}
```

Resultado:

```
jose
juan
carlos
luis
```

Demo:

https://3v4l.org/RVJi6

Comment: Usando preg_match_all() me da este resultado **Array**

Comment: Si ocupo mi código y le añado preg_match_all() no funciona

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions agregué el código y una demo online... Está bien que te devuelva un array con todos los resultados. El tema es mostrarlo correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por el dato funciona bien solo me resta pedirte ayuda para limpiar el array  y crear la lista de nombres uno por linea . gracias

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions editado... Te recomiendo leer [la ayuda de PHP sobre arrays](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php). Te va a ser útil para cualquier cosa que programes.

Comment: Gracias amigo ya lo solucione de esta manera : foreach($mp as $final){
echo $final ."<br/>";
}

Comment: Gracias  tema solucionado